# Current UTC time independant from system clock?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need the correct time in UTC no matter what the system time is set to and also the timezone the machine is in.

(Even if I have to make a call to the internet to sync up...)

Is there some library or other way to do this elegantly?

Comment: Good reason not to trust your server time ?

Comment: after checking the system time in two of my aws instances I realised that they were both 3 minutes apart.

Comment: You should fix server time. [According to this post]( https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=101998), ntpd is setup by default when using AWS ami, are you using a custom image ?

Comment: Yes its one of the community debian wheey distributions. I have an install script that prepares our machines with essentialls so I will add some lines it to sync time. Or is there a way to make aws do it for me on custom images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get accurate reliable time then you need to use NTP(Network time protocol) to read time from one of the public respected NTP servers more info on below links

For Node there are two ways you can get time using one of the actual NTP client implemented as Node module one i have used is [[this ntp client ]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntp-client)

```js
var ntpClient = require('ntp-client');
 
ntpClient.getNetworkTime("pool.ntp.org", 123, function(err, date) {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
 
    console.log("Current time : ");
    console.log(date); // Mon Jul 08 2013 21:31:31 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)) 
});
```

There are JSON api's which gives you time in JSON format you can google for them

Comment: what about syncing this with some construct to be able to call the accurate time later on without making ntp calls?

Comment: once you have a time then you can keep it in your records then do periodic calls to check if its still accurate..but those periodic calls doesn't have to be too often.

Comment: local time or increment it on your code will always have small drifts but those are very small for 30 mins period..let me know if this helps

Comment: I am actually working on something that deals with precise timing where multiple machines need to be in proper sync. I think the best is to just go with what @Gabriel suggested and make sure that the machines have proper time instead of making the code independant from it. This is however the correct anwser to the question.